# Django admin IPAddressField does not allow *.*.*.*

Tags: django, django-admin

How to allow IPAddressField to accept string *.*.*.*?

Now everytime, I tried to save, I received Enter a valid IPv4 address. error.

Comment: Well... yeah. That's not a valid IP address. Perhaps you should describe what you're *really* after.

Comment: i would assume that Kelvin wants any ip address.

Comment: "Any IP address" is an address of 0.0.0.0 with a mask of 0 or 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    ipfield = forms.CharField()

    def clean_ipfield(self):        
        value = self.cleaned_data['ipfield']
        # Check if they saved an IP, only use this if the field is required
        if not value:
            if self.fields['ipfield'].required:
                raise forms.ValidationError('No IP was given')
            else:
                return value

        ip = value.split('.')

        # Make sure the ip has atleast 4 parts to it
        # Upto 8 are required for IPv6
        if 4 > len(ip) or len(ip) > 8 :
            raise forms.ValidationError('An invalid IP address was entered')

        # Check that all parts are digits or '*' (additional checks can be done here too)
        for i in ip:
            if i != '*' and not i.isdigit():
                raise forms.ValidationError('%s is not a valid IP part' % i)

        return '.'.join(ip)
```

Not sure if this is what you're after or not. Instead of using the actual IpAddressField() you could use a CharField() and provide the custom validations yourself, like so.
Note that YourForm is the name of your actual form and ipfield is the name of your current IpAddressField.

Hope that helps.